# Charles Config "SAXException: XML document is not a Charles session"

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy

When starting the Charles proxy using

```
Charles -config charles-config.xml
```

I get the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: XML document is not a Charles session
```

The Java version I use is

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

This is even though I create the charles-config.xml file using Charles itself
Charles -> Tools -> Import/Export Settings

My Charles version v4.5.6 and OS version is Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: It shows the same exact error to me. Can't really help on this. I think you better ask them (the Charles Proxy team) for support on this, they will probably be interested in fixing this error too.

Comment: @LluísSuñol Thanks for the feedback, at least its good to know its reproducible